# Howto create Python Pyramid view class without need to specify 'name' for each method

Tags: python, forms, post, view, pyramid

I have several view classes in my Python Pyramid project added via add_handler:

```
config.add_handler('export_index', '/export', handler=ExportViews, action='index')

class ExportViews(ConfigViewBase):
    @action(request_method='POST', name='index',
            request_param='ftp_export.form.submitted')
    @action(request_method='POST', name='index', xhr=True, renderer='json',
            request_param='ftp_export.form.submitted')
    def ftp_export(self):
         #process form
         return {}

    @action(request_method='GET')
    def index(self):
        return {}
```

Is it possible to do the same having:

```
config.add_handler('export_index', '/export', handler=ExportViews)

class ExportViews(ConfigViewBase):
    @action(request_method='POST',
            request_param='ftp_export.form.submitted')
    @action(request_method='POST', xhr=True, renderer='json',
            request_param='ftp_export.form.submitted')
    def ftp_export(self):
         #process form
         return {}

    @action(request_method='GET')
    def __call__(self):
        return {}
```

So the __call__ was called when browser gets page, and ftp_export should be called when I post form on the same page. Now I get `page not found error`

Thank You.

Comment: this behavior isn't supported in pyramid_handlers right now

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with traversal. Traversal rocks :)

```
class Root(object):
    def  __getitem__(self, name):
        if name == "export":
            return ExportSomething(self)
        if name == "export_something_else":
            return ExportSomethingElse(self)



class ExportSomething(object):

    implements(IViewable, IExportable)

    def view(self, request):
        return "Hi"

    def export(self, request):
        return "something else"

@view_config(context=IViewable, request_method="GET")
def view_viewable(conext, request):
    return context.view(request)

@view_config(context=IExportable, request_method="POST")
def export_exportable(conext, request):
    return context.export(request)
```

then you can implement a bunch of `ExportThis` and `ExportThat` classes, make them implement `IViewable` and `IExportable` interfaces, make them returned from `Root.__getitem__` and everything magically works. Or, if you don't need multiple exporters you can omit interfaces and bind views directly to `ExportSomething` class. Or you can instantiate different instances of `ExportSomething` in **getitem** and make it to... I don't know, view/export different files/reports.

Comment: if at `/export` you have Export, he can do something like `view_config(context=IExportable, name="fun")` to match `/export/fun`. Traversal is pretty awesome yes.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `view_defaults` with `view_config` instead of pyramid_handler